# Load jquery preloader animation, earlier

Tags: javascript, css, preloader

I installed [fakeLoader](http://joaopereirawd.github.io/fakeLoader.js/) (jquery preloader) but I have trouble making it show before the page loads.

In mozilla it works almost fine (strangely...), but in Chrome and Opera, the page loads first and then the preloader animation takes place.

You could check my full source code here: http://morph.ellevenacoustica.com/

As the instructions in fakeloader website say, I load jquery 1.11.1 and fakeloader.js and .css in head.
Then I place a   `<div id="fakeloader"></div>` on top of body and then I load this script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#fakeloader").fakeLoader({ timeToHide:1200, zIndex:9999, spinner:"spinner1", bgColor:"#a01414" });});</script>
```

The full javascript of fakeloader.js can also be found at the link that I provided above.

I contacted the creator of the script at github but unfortunately I got no answer, so I rely on you to give me a helping hand!

Comment: The link that you gave us have errors. Please correct the errors to checl your full source

Comment: "In mozilla it works almost fine (strangely...)" - why it should be strange? Firefox is decent browser - i see more questions here on SO related to Chrome problems, actually... :)

Comment: It does not have error, maybe you just had a bad timing. Please check again if you can. Thank you.

Comment: The strange thing is not that I consider mozila a bad browser. It happens to be my default browser. I love it. I just think it is strange that it works fine in a browser and not in an other.

Comment: $(document).ready( makes the script load after document is ready

Comment: I understand that... but when i change it to $(document).load it doesnt work at all. I am missing something here...

Comment: Also when I completely remove the $(document).ready as in the instructions, it does not display at all.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I am proud of myself! :P

The correct code to be placed at the bottom is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
$("#fakeloader").fakeLoader({ 
timeToHide:1200, 
zIndex:9999, 
spinner:"spinner1", 
bgColor:"#a01414" 
});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```